# Why high IO rate operations slow everything on linux?

Tags: linux, multicore

This may be slightly OT, but I was wondering why having a process which heavily uses IO (say cp big file from one location to the other on the same disk) slows everything down, even processes which are mostly CPU bound. I noticed that on both OS I heavily use (mac os x and linux).

In particular, I wonder why multi-core does not really help here: is it a hardware limitation for commodity hardware (disk controller, etc...), an os limitation, or is there something inherently hard into allocating the right resources (scheduling) ?

Comment: They slow everything on Windows too.  I believe it is because the CPU cannot manage BUS operations and CPU operations simultaneously, but I'm sure someone here has a better response.

Comment: The situation is much worse on Windows. Windows even throttles IO throughput to try and keep things usable. This is why it performs so poorly in many benchmarks.

Comment: "even processes which are mostly CPU bound" -- These processes might be "I/O bound" too: i.e. *RAM* I/O. I'd guess the story would be different if you can find (or make) a CPU-bound process that's mostly/only executing data in its on-board cache.

Comment: Incidentally I read once that the reason why mainframe computers are considered fast is not especially the CPU, but the fact that they have a prodigious I/O bandwidth.

Comment: Also I disagree with this question being closed as "off-topic": IMO it's relevent to programming to know at least this much about hardware.

Comment: This question has acquired much interest. Lets hope we get a worthy answer.

Comment: @ChrisW: if RAM communication is considered as IO, then almost any process is IO bound, no ? I agree the expression is not very meaningful and does not have a strict definition.

Comment: @David no? Yes; and I put "I/O bound" in [scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes). It depends on your POV: from the POV of the CPU, RAM is I/O; from the POV of the 'system' (e.g. the motherboard), 'external' devices are I/O. In common usage (for a programmer rather than a hardware engineer) I think that I/O always refers to the network, usually or often refers to the hard drive too, and rarely if ever refers to the RAM.

Comment: Great question. I've experienced this problem many times but never thought to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, copying a large file (bigger than the available buffer cache) usually involves bringing it through the buffer cache, which generally causes less recently-used pages to be thrown out, which must then be brought back in.

Other processes which are doing tiny small amounts of occasional IO (say just stat'ing a directory) then get their caches all blown away and must do physical reads to bring those pages back in.

Hopefully this can get fixed by a copy-command which can detect this kind of thing and advise the kernel accordingly (e.g. with posix_fadvise) so that a large one-off bulk transfer of a file which does not need to be subsequently read does not completely discard all clean pages from the buffer cache, which now normally mostly happens.

Comment: So you're saying it's the file system's cache, not the CPUs' caches.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the filesystem's cache. A copy command could, in principle, copy a very large file without blowing most of the cache away; it's simply that they typically don't.

Comment: is there a simple way to see whether your answer is more likely right than caf's one ? Both seem reasonable to me. I did not know about posix_fadvise. It looks like implementing a simple cp using POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED could avoid trashing the buffer cache ?

Comment: I'm not sure whose answer is right. I guess that implementing such a file copy wouldn't be too difficult. You'd need to do fsync() periodically on the destination file so that the buffer cache doesn't fill up with dirty blocks and push out more important things; posix_fadvise will only tell the kernel to get rid of clean ones. The "low impact copy" could also ionice() itself as well which will de-prioritise its IO request in some cases.

Comment: Either answer could be "right" to varying degrees - there's possible reasons for performance impacts, and which of those reasons will dominate depends on the exact nature of the tasks you're running (and the system you're running them on).

Answer (score 5):

It could be a limitation of the current scheduler.  Google "Galbraith's sched:autogroup patch" or "linux miracle patch" (yes really!).  There's apparently a 200-line patch in the process of being refined and merged which adds group scheduling, about which [Linus says](http://lkml.org/lkml/2010/11/14/222):

> I'm also very happy with just what it does to interactive performance.
>   Admittedly, my "testcase" is really trivial (reading email in a
>   web-browser, scrolling around a bit, while doing a "make -j64" on the
>   kernel at the same time), but it's a test-case that is very relevant
>   for me. And it is a *huge* improvement.

Before-and-after videos [here](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/News/Galbraith-Linux-kernel-scheduling-patch/).

Comment: Somehow I think this is unrelated, however it's nice to mention it. The patch has to do with CPU-contention, not IO.

Comment: I'm not sure it's unrelated.  Linux noted that it significantly helped processes which he himself assumed were I/O bound.

Comment: Yes in hindsight I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

A high rate of IO operations usually means a high rate of interrupts that must be serviced by the CPU, which takes CPU time.

In the case of `cp`, it also uses a considerable amount of the available memory bandwidth, as each block of data is copied to and from userspace.  This will also tend to eject data required by other processes from the CPUs caches and TLB, which will slow down other processes as they take cache misses.

Comment: I don't think it's directly attributable to the CPU time being spent at interrupt-level: I think you'll find that's not a big percentage of the total CPU utilization.

Comment: Doesn't each CPU have its own, semi-indendent cache? If so then are you sure that data is ejected from the caches of CPUs running CPU-bound processes?

Comment: @ChrisW: The OP mentions "multi-core" - two cores in the same package often share the same L2 cache - and depending on the number of tasks contending for the CPUs, `cp` may be scheduled on a CPU that was running a CPU-bound task.

Comment: @caf: so it would be contention around the cache and TLB ? This is clearly a level at which I barely know anything. I think highend CPU has separate caches per core, but for uniform memory architectures, it seems that you need a globally coherent TLB, right ? Do high end hardware suffer from similar issues ?

Comment: @caf: not that I don't trust your answer, but would you have a reference that I could check to get a better understanding of the phenomenon ? Also, would you know a way to validate your hypothesis on linux, e.g. number of interrupts while doing IO intensive operations. Can you access any kind of statistics on TLB usage from userspace ?

Comment: @David Cournapeau: The contention could be in different places depending on the exact nature of the load.  You can use [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/) to examine CPU performance counters, which could help to confirm what's happening in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, would you know a way to validate your hypothesis on linux, e.g. number of interrupts while doing IO intensive operations.

To do with interrupts, I'm guessing that caf's hypothesis is:

- many interrupts per second;
- interrupts are serviced by any/all CPUs;
- therefore, interrupts flush the CPU caches.

The statistics you'd need to test that would be the number of interrupts per second per CPU.

I don't know whether it's possible to tie interrupts to a single CPU: see http://www.google.com/#q=cpu+affinity+interrupt for further details.

Here's something I don't understand (this is the first time I've looked at this question): perfmon on my laptop (running Windows Vista) is showing 2000 interrupts/second (1000 on each core) when it's almost idle (doing nothing but displaying perfmon). I can't imagine which device is generating 2000 interrupts/second, and I would have thought that's enough to blow away the CPU caches (my guess is that the CPU quantum for a busy thread is something like 50 msec). It's also showing an average of 350 DPCs/sec.

> Do high end hardware suffer from similar issues ?

One type of hardware difference might be the disk hardware and disk device driver, generating more or fewer interrupts and/or other contentions.

Comment: Real Time Clock, mouse moves, keyboard presses are all handled via interrupts